# Keras problem adding KL-divergence to model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have a variational autoencoder with recurrent layers implementation in Keras, which works well as a regenerative model, very accurately reconstructing the input. I have been using an implementation of KL-divergence from this tutorial: 
`http://louistiao.me/posts/implementing-variational-autoencoders-in-keras-beyond-the-quickstart-tutorial/`
which looks like this:

```
class KLDivergenceLayer(Layer):

    """ Identity transform layer that adds KL divergence
    to the final model loss.
    """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.is_placeholder = True
        super(KLDivergenceLayer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def call(self, inputs):

        mu, log_var = inputs

        kl_batch = - .5 * K.sum(1 + log_var -
                                K.square(mu) -
                                K.exp(log_var), axis=-1)

        self.add_loss(K.mean(kl_batch), inputs=inputs)

        return inputs
```

My model works well, right up until this layer is added, then it seems to just generate random noise, but I cannot for the life of me figure out why. The calculation of KL-divergence looks correct.
This is the code for my model:

```
def sampling(args):
    z_mean, z_log_var = args
    batch = keras.backend.shape(z_mean)[0]
    timestep = keras.backend.int_shape(z_mean)[1]
    feature = keras.backend.int_shape(z_mean)[2]

    epsilon = keras.backend.random_normal(shape=(batch, timestep, feature))
    return z_mean + keras.backend.exp(0.5 * z_log_var) * epsilon


def make_encoder(window_size, features, gru_dim, dense_dim):
    input = keras.Input(shape=(window_size, features), name='encoder_input')
    gru = keras.layers.GRU(gru_dim, return_sequences=True, name='encoder_gru')(input)
    dense = keras.layers.Dense(dense_dim, name='encoder_dense', activation='relu')(gru)
    z_mean = keras.layers.Dense(features, name='encoder_z_mean', activation='linear')(dense)
    z_log_var = keras.layers.Dense(features, name='encoder_z_log_var', activation='softplus')(dense)
    z_mean, z_log_var = KLDivergenceLayer()([z_mean, z_log_var])
    z_sample = keras.layers.Lambda(sampling, name='encoder_z_sample',
                                   output_shape=(None, window_size, features))([z_mean, z_log_var])

    encoder = keras.Model(input, [z_mean, z_log_var, z_sample], name='encoder')
    return encoder, input


def make_decoder(window_size, features, gru_dim, dense_dim):
    input = keras.Input(shape=(window_size, features), name='decoder_input')
    gru = keras.layers.GRU(gru_dim, return_sequences=True, name='decoder_gru')(input)
    dense = keras.layers.Dense(dense_dim, name='decoder_dense', activation='relu')(gru)
    z_mean = keras.layers.Dense(features, name='decoder_z_mean', activation='linear')(dense)
    z_log_var = keras.layers.Dense(features, name='decoder_z_log_var', activation='softplus')(dense)
    z_mean, z_log_var = KLDivergenceLayer()([z_mean, z_log_var])
    xt_sample = keras.layers.Lambda(sampling, name='decoder_xt_sample')([z_mean, z_log_var])
    output_layer = keras.layers.Activation('sigmoid', name='decoder_output')(xt_sample)

    decoder = keras.Model(input, output_layer, name='decoder')
    return decoder


def make_model(window_size, features, gru_dim, dense_dim):
    encoder, encoder_input = make_encoder(window_size, features, gru_dim, dense_dim)
    decoder = make_decoder(window_size, features, gru_dim, dense_dim)
    decoder_output = decoder(encoder(encoder_input)[2])

    rvae = keras.Model(encoder_input, decoder_output, name='rvae')
    return rvae
```